# Cloudant authentication and XACML

Tags: authentication, wso2, couchdb, cloudant, xacml

Any recommendations for implementing xacml with cloudant (couchdb)?  I know that mapreduce poses certain issues but am curious if anyone has been creative and worked it out or is working on it - or for instance managed to get it working with wso2.

Answer (score 0):

Go through these posts,

- [How to develop a Stratos docker cartridge for CouchDB](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-develop-stratos-docker-cartridge.html)
- [How to add CouchDB docker cartridge to Apache Stratos](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-add-couchdb-docker-cartridge-to.html)
- [How to Publish First CouchApp Using Stratos CouchDB Cartridge](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-publish-first-couchapp-using.html)

Hope this helps!